# Constructing short description using HTML?

Tags: html, magento

I am trying to put a link in the short description that say's Read More... and then when the buyer clicks on it, it will take them to the main description further down the product page.

Please could you help with how to do this.
The URL is the same as the product page then has a # on the end.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you already tried? We tend not to write people's code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Add an anchor pointing to your full description id: `<a href="#yourFullDescription">Read more</a>`